# A single report containing credit card types and transactions

Tags: reports

Not a Magento expert here, but gotta figure this out.

My team wants to be able to see a report in Magento that puts the credit card type next to each transaction all in one sheet.

we can click in to each order, but as we increase in number of transactions, this will be too time consuming.  Can someone help us figure out if this is at all possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A company we work with is beta testing a SaaS OLAP for Magento with fixed and ad-hoc reporting, let us know and we can connect you.

Answer (score 1):

We would need to know more about what payment processor you use but your best bet is to look into the sales_flat_order_payment table and see if your payment processor's module stores card type.  If not then you'll have to see if the payment processor's api returns card type, then store it and report on it yourself.